# Peek Definition doesn't work with JavaScript on vs 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

I have started using visual studio 2015 with a JavaScript project and I noticed the Peek Definition feature doesn't work.
In contrast, the regular Go To Definition works just fine.

I tried both pressing Alt+F12 and right-click > Peek Definition, but it does nothing (I don't see any response to this anywhere).

I also tried installing 'Productivity Power Tools' to use the Ctrl+Click feature but it also does nothing.

What might be the problem?
Thank you